# Rewrite Rule how to make for folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 folder on my FTP.

www/

www/test/

So..

example.com

example.com/test

In folder test
 is htaccess with

```
RewriteRule booking\.php booking.php
```

but when i click on link

```
<a href"/booking">Link</a>
```

Redirect me to
https://example.com/booking

but I need redirect to
https://example.com/test/booking

Can you help me please?

I know how to make with link

```
<a href="/test/booking">
```

but I need make this with htaccess.

Comment: shouldn't your rewrite rule include `test` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use The rewrite rule that uses `^$` because this represents the root and rewrite that to your folder /test , like this:

Use this method:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /test [L]
```

Or this method:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [NC,L]
```